# unexpected SyntaxError from Template/Ajax - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, ajax, phtml

I am a newby in Magento, so sorry if my question seem stupid.
I have an error

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected double-quoted property name at line 6 column 17 of the JSON data

that I don't understand, I mean I don't use JSON.parse and problem seems to come from this Magento core but I don't understant why.
Here my .phtml :

```
    <input type='button' id='zip_btn' name='zip_btn'>  <style>   .hideme{display:none;} </style> <script type="text/x-magento-init">
            {
                "*": {
                    "Vendor_ZipCode/web/js/ajax": {
                        "AjaxUrl": "<?php echo $block->getAjaxUrl(); ?>",
                    }
                }
            } </script> <div id='test' class="hideme">
        <select>
          <% _.each(posts, function(text,value) { %>
             <option value="<%= value %>"><%= text %></option>
          <% }) %> 
         </select> </div>
```

and here js:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'mage/template',
    'jquery/list-filter'
    ], function (
        $,
        _,
        template
    ) {
        function main(config, element) {
            var $element = $(element);
            var zipurl = config.AjaxUrl;
            console.log('test');
            $(document).on('click','#zip_btn',function() {
                    var param = 'ajax=1';
                        $.ajax({
                            showLoader: true,
                            url: zipurl,
                            data: param,
                            type: "POST",
                            dataType: 'json'
                        }).done(function (data) {
                            $('#test').removeClass('hideme');
                            var html = template('#test', {posts:data}); 
                            $('#test').html(html);
                        });
                });
        };
    console.log('test');
    return main;
```

If someone know the answer I would be really glad.
please in case you put minus explain while like that I can improve the post ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of this line `"AjaxUrl": "<?php echo $block->getAjaxUrl(); ?>",` there is a comma (`,`) that should not be there.
Make the line look like this `"AjaxUrl": "<?php echo $block->getAjaxUrl(); ?>"`

Comment: Thank you it work :) just now Magento "The Great" change by another error Error: Script error for: Vendor_ZipCode/web/js/ajax
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror